# Muting individual landlines and skype lines so that people can answer questions in a class or conference

Tags: skype, mute

I want to conference call in people on landlines and Skype and then mute / unmute certain ones.  It seems that this can be done to Skype users on the conference call but not landlines.  I've read about skypecast being able to do this.  Is this possible?

Comment: Where did you read about it? Can you post the link(s)?